# C++ Interest Calculating Program

Tags: c++

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
double amount;
double rate;
int numPayments;
double payment = (rate * pow((1 + rate), numPayments) /            (pow((1+rate),numPayments)-1)) * amount;

cout << "Loan amount: " << endl;
cin >> amount;
cout << "Monthly interest rate (.12 for 12%): " << endl;
cin >> rate;
cout << "Number of monthly payments to be made: " << endl;
cin >> numPayments;

cout << "Loan amount: " << amount << endl;
cout << "Monthly interest rate: " << rate << endl;
cout << "Number of Payments: " << numPayments << endl;
cout << "Monthly payment: " << (amount/numPayments)*rate;
cout << "Amount paid back: " << (amount*rate)+amount;
cout << "Interest paid: " << amount*rate;
}
```

Hi, I'm trying to code a fairly simple interest calculating program... keep getting 'initialized local variable used.'  I'm fairly new to C++ so i'm sure it's something simple...

Comment: One thing to note is that when you do an assignment, you're doing the calculation given the current state. It's not like a formula where you can update `amount` and expect to see `payment` correspondingly change.

Comment: initialize your values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have coded it you're calculating the payment before the user enters the values for amount, rate, numPayments.

This line

```
double payment = (rate * pow((1 + rate), numPayments) /            (pow((1+rate),numPayments)-1)) * amount;
```

needs to execute *after* the lines where you read variables from the user i.e.;

```
cout << "Loan amount: " << endl;
cin >> amount;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; it is below the cin variables.

Comment: It looks like you've tried to set payment to a formula like in Excel, so that as the variables in it change, payment also changes; this doesn't happen.  It takes the variables at their current values at that line of execution, so you need to put that line after where you **set** your cin variables.

Comment: "I'm not sure what you mean; it is below the cin variables. – user2109696" - look again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the question really is... but I don't think this will work.

```
double amount;
double rate;
int numPayments;
double payment = (rate * pow((1 + rate), numPayments) /            (pow((1+rate),numPayments)-1)) * amount;
```

Because you didn't initialize them with a value, they will have random values. That's why shouldn't use `rate` in `payment` here.

I would suggest to initialize them with 0.

```
double amount = 0.0;
double rate = 0.0;
int numPayments = 0;

cout << "Loan amount: " << endl;
cin >> amount;
cout << "Monthly interest rate (.12 for 12%): " << endl;
cin >> rate;
cout << "Number of monthly payments to be made: " << endl;
cin >> numPayments;

double payment = (rate * pow((1 + rate), numPayments) / pow((1+rate),numPayments)-1)) * amount;

//Now you can print
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Mike, you need to assign ("give a value") the variables before using them.
You can move the assignment of payment after getting the input data, like this:

```
double amount;
double rate;
int numPayments;
double payment;

cout << "Loan amount: " << endl;
cin >> amount;
cout << "Monthly interest rate (.12 for 12%): " << endl;
cin >> rate;
cout << "Number of monthly payments to be made: " << endl;
cin >> numPayments;

payment = (rate * pow((1 + rate), numPayments) / (pow((1+rate),numPayments)-1)) * amount;
```